# Sum of combinations - convergence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory

I am trying to evaluate the sum of combinations for a specific probability problem, but I am kind of stuck.

Let A have toss a coin $n+1$ times and B toss another coin $n$ times. What is the probability that A has more heads than B. (the probability of heads is $P = 1/2$). All experiments are independent.

Now, let $X$ denote the numbers of heads A has and $Y$ the number of heads B has. So:

$$ \begin{eqnarray} P(X>Y) &= \sum_{y=0}^{n}P(X>y|Y=y) P(Y=y) \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X>y|Y=y) {n \choose y} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\ 
&= \sum_{y=0}^{n} \sum_{x=y+1}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose x} {n \choose y} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n+1} \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n+1} \sum_{y=0}^{n} \sum_{x=y+1}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose x} {n \choose y} \end{eqnarray} $$

I know this sum must result $2^{2n}$, because the probability must be $1/2$. Yet I am stuck. Any advices?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you mean $2^{2n}$?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Corrected it already

Comment: I assume you are aware of the symmetry argument? Let $E_H$ (resp. $E_T$) be the event in which $A$ tosses *strictly* more heads (resp. tails) than $B$. Since $E_H$ and $E_T$ partition the space and are equivalent up to a relabeling, then $P(E_H) = P(E_T) = 1/2$. Are you just looking to reproduce the same result **not** using this argument?

Comment: Equivalent to what parsiad said, imagine that one player flips a fair coin $2n+1$ times, beginning with a score of zero. Every other flip beginning with the first is an “A-flip,” where heads increases the score by one and tails decreases it by one. The other flips are “B-flips,” which have the opposite effect. After $2n+1$ flips, what is the probability of a positive score? There are an odd number of flips, so the final score can’t be zero, and the game is symmetric, so the probability of positive and negative scores are each $1/2$.

Comment: Yes, @parsiad, I'm aware of such argument. Yet I want to reproduce this by an alternative result, with the sum of combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the one hand we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=y+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}}
> &=\sum_{y=0}^n\left(2^{n+1}-\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\right)\binom{n}{y}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{2n+1}-\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> on  the other hand we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=y+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}}
> &=\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=n+1-y}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=-y}^0\binom{n+1}{x+n+1}\binom{n}{y}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{n+1-x}\binom{n}{y}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}}\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing  (2)  and (6) we observe
>
> \begin{align*}
> 2^{2n+1}-\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}&=\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}\\
> \color{blue}{\sum_{y=0}^n\sum_{x=0}^y\binom{n+1}{x}\binom{n}{y}}&\color{blue}{=2^{2n}}
> \end{align*}
>
> and    the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) and (2) we use $\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}=2^n$.
- In (3) we change the order of summation $y\to n-y$ and we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (4) we shift the index $x$ by $n+1$.
- In (5) we substitute $x$ with $-x$.
- In (6) we use again $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much Markus! :)

Comment: @M.Gonzalez: You're welcome. Thanks for your nice comment. :-)